# What is the recommended way to Typset/Format Algorithm-related questions?

Tags: algorithms

What is the recommended way to typeset algorithms?

For example, I have a question about an algorithm related to automata theory, and I would like to render the algorithm in my question.

In Latex I would use the `algorithmic` package and then get on with `STATE` and `WHILE`, etc.  This does not seem to work here however, so is it recommended that I format the algorithm in html, with a numbered, ordered list and the individual details in jsmath/latex or is there some other tacitly agreed upon protocol?

Comment: This type of question is more appropriate over at the meta site.

Comment: Closed: this is for meta.

Answer (score 2):

To display code, indent it four spaces -- this is the markdown syntax for code blocks. For example:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial 0 = 1 
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

If you need to put some code inline, then put it in backticks -- "`Integer` is a type". Unfortunately the code block code seems to suppress jsMath, however.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but definitely need a solution that supports both the algorithm notation and mathjs style markup.  I guess html is the way to go?

Comment: sadly, no.  The formatter allows very little by way of actual HTML.  I recommend that you search on meta as there are several discussions with links there that may help you.